# IsolatedStorageSettings access raises first-chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, exception, isolatedstorage, .net

I'm creating a settings view and a "related" settings class like described here:

[How to: Create a Settings Page for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769510%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

This is not my first attempt but this thime i got a **first-chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll** when i try to get the ApplicationSettings from IsolatedStorageSettings. This happens in the view code behind and in related viewmodel, in other parts of my app (i.e. code behind or viewmodel of other views) it works fine. Why???

Here's the code:

AppSettings.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Windows;

namespace MetanoInLombardia
{
    public class AppSettings
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings;

        const string IsAutoUpdateOn_KeyName = "AutoUpdateOn"; 

        const bool IsAutoUpdateOn_Default = true;

        public AppSettings()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
                {
                    settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception while using IsolatedStorageSettings in AppSettings(): " + e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
        {
            if (settings.Contains(Key))
            {
                if (settings[Key] != value)
                {
                    settings[Key] = value;
                    Save();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                settings.Add(Key, value);
                Save();
            }
        }

        public T GetValueOrDefault<T>(string Key, T defaultValue)
        {
            if (!settings.Contains(Key))
            {
                AddOrUpdateValue(Key, defaultValue);
            }
            return (T)settings[Key];
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            settings.Save();
        }

        public bool IsAutoUpdateOn
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValueOrDefault<bool>(IsAutoUpdateOn_KeyName, IsAutoUpdateOn_Default);
            }
            set
            {
                AddOrUpdateValue(IsAutoUpdateOn_KeyName, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SettingsViewModel.cs [extract]

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using MetanoInLombardia.Model;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

namespace MetanoInLombardia.ViewModel
{
    public class SettingsViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IDataService _dataService;
        private AppSettings settings = null;

        public SettingsViewModel(IDataService dataService)
        {
            _dataService = dataService;

            _dataService.GetApplicationTitle(
                (item, error) =>
                {
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    ApplicationTitle = item.Title;
                });

            this.settings = new AppSettings();
        }
...
    }
}
```

I got exception in AppSettings.cs, in row

```
settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you, i apologize for this^^

Comment: No need for apologies. Now you know.